# Copying a vector into an array using Iterators

Tags: c++, r, iterator, rcpp

I've been attempting to copy a vector into an array with no luck. I'm not that familiar with iterators, which seem to be the best choice, but I've been unable to get the copy to work correctly. Here's the code:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
  Rcpp::LogicalMatrix mateFamily(const Rcpp::LogicalVector& parent1, 
                                 const Rcpp::LogicalVector& parent2) {
    // init
      int i, AllCount, crossPt, crossCol;
      AllCount = parent1.length();
      Rcpp::LogicalVector child1(AllCount), child2(AllCount);
      Rcpp::LogicalMatrix matePop(6,AllCount);
    // print parents
      std::cout << "parent1=" << parent1 << '\n';
      std::cout << "parent2=" << parent2 << '\n';
    // create 6 children
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {  
      // determine crossover location
         crossPt = i + 1;
         crossCol = 3*(crossPt==1) + 6*(crossPt==2) + 9*(crossPt==3);
      // swap
         // child1 = parent1/parent2
           std::copy(parent1.begin(), parent1.end(), child1.begin());
           std::copy(parent2.begin()+crossCol, parent2.end(), child1.begin()+crossCol);
         // child2 = parent2/parent1
           std::copy(parent2.begin(), parent2.end(), child2.begin());
           std::copy(parent1.begin()+crossCol, parent1.end(), child2.begin()+crossCol);
         // print children
           std::cout << "child1= " << child1 << '\n';
           std::cout << "child2= " << child2 << '\n';
         // copy children into matePop
           std::copy(child1.begin(), child1.end(), matePop.begin()+i*AllCount);
           std::copy(child2.begin(), child2.end(), matePop.begin()+i*AllCount);
    }
    std::cout << "matePop=" << '\n' << matePop << '\n';
    return matePop;
  }
```

The genetic crossover code works and creates the correct children combinations, but I can't figure out how to copy all 6 children into matePop.

The test parents as defined in R for this simplified example are:

```
    parent1 <- cbind(1,1,1, 1,1,1, 1,1,1, 1,1,1)
    parent2 <- cbind(0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The crossover section works. Here's the output:

```
parent1=  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1     
parent2=  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1    
 child1=  1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1  
 child2=  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
 child1=  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1  
 child2=  0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
 child1=  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1  
 child2=  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Here's the matePop output:

```
matePop=
100110011100
100110011100
111111111111
001110011001
001110011001
111111111111
```

So the mystery is when the children get copied into matePop

Comment: So you can't figure up the `// copy children into matePop` part, and everything above that works fine?

Comment: I added the output above

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead:

```
std::copy(child1.begin(), child1.end(), matePop.begin()+2*i*AllCount);
std::copy(child2.begin(), child2.end(), matePop.begin()+(2*i+1)*AllCount);
```

matePop is a 2d matrix with 6 rows and `AllCount` columns. So for the first time you'll be copying into rows 0 and 1. Second time into 2 & 3 and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that index mistake. I made the fix, but the output is still not loading into matePop properly. Output is shown above.

Comment: I diagnosed the issue with the matePop output matrix. The iterator is loading the child values in "vertically" rather than "horizontally." Strange behaviour. I can code in a workaround, but I wonder what's causing the issue.

Comment: @Sean S R uses (and thus Rcpp, `Rcpp::Matrix`, etc.) column-major ordering, not row-major ordering, so calling e.g. `std::copy(src1.begin(), src1.end(), dst.begin())`, `std::copy(src2.begin(), src2.end(), dst.begin() + std::distance(src1.begin(), src1.end()))`, ..., will fill the destination object column-by-column, not row-by-row.